# <__main__.myClass object at 0x000001CCDC46BD90> instead of expected string output

Tags: python, whiteboard

Write a Python class which has two methods `get_String` and `print_String`. `get_String` should accept a string from the user and `print_String` should print the string in upper case.

**My Code:**

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, userInput = input("What is your name? ")):
        self.userInput = userInput
    def get_string(userInput):
        return userInput
    def print_string(userInput):
        output = userInput.upper()
        return output
print(myClass())
```

```
Terminal:
What is your name? Anthony
<__main__.myClass object at 0x000001CCDC46BD90>
```

Should have come out as:

```
ANTHONY
```

Comment: Please show some sample input and output for that input. Then say what you expected to see as output instead.

Comment: *Why* do you think it should output `ANTHONY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing the fundamentals re: classes in Python:

1. The assignment asks you to get the string using the `get_string` method, not during `__init__`.
2. Your `print_string` should print the stored string, it shouldn't require the user to pass a new string.
3. You are not attempting to convert the string to uppercase anywhere in your code.

Here is an improved version:

```python
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None

    def get_string(self):
        self.name = input("What is your name? ")

    def print_string(self):
        print(self.name.upper())


my_object = MyClass()
my_object.get_string()
my_object.print_string()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can rearrange your code a bit so that the methods read the input and then print it out in the required format:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.userInput = None
    def get_String(self):
        self.userInput = input('What is your name? ')
    def print_String(self):
        print(self.userInput.upper())

# Instantiate the object
x = myClass()

# Read the name
x.get_String()

# Print the name
x.print_String()

# This prints:
#
# What is your name? Anthony
# ANTHONY
```

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your `print_string` method by passing the `self` argument and then call with the `print_string()` method.

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, userInput = input("What is your name? ")):
        self.userInput = userInput
    def print_string(self):
        output = self.userInput.upper()
        return output
print(myClass().print_string())
```